# C# Referencing Quartz.DLL. Error on Debug losing Reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio, quartz.net

I'm trying to build a simple scheduler using Quartz.NET, but when I try to run my program it "loses" the reference and gives me 8 errors.  If I re-add the reference, which never actually disappeared, the errors go away, but the program just does the same thing.  I'm working on the project on a Team Server Foundation which is completely new to me.  I committed the changes, but I simply can't get the third-party references to stick.

I saved the Quartz.DLL in my project in a lib folder.

Here's a screenshot of the errors I'm receiving. 
[image: screenshot with errors]

I should also note that I'm not really super familiar with C# or Visual Studios.  Any advice on how to add and manage a third-party library would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is the `using System.DateTime;` above `using Quartz;`. Try removing that to see if it fixes the issues.

Also, if you are running Quartz 2.0, you need to be sure that you are targetting at least the .Net 3.5 framework, not 2.0. See the breaking changes information [here](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Thank you.  It was the framework.  I didn't set the project up and we were using 4.0 Client Profile.  Switched it to 4.0 and it works fine.

Comment: That's excellent news. Would you mind clicking on the checkbox next to the answer so that future visitors to this answer will know that is what resolved the issue for you? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

check if your project's properties is running under .net 4.0 and not client profile.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on Home_Control project. `Select properties >> Select Application tab >> Look for the Target framework: >> Change it to` .Net Framework 4 (Note: Please select the appropriate version depending on your project. Please Don't Select .Net Framework 4 Client Profile or .Net Framework 3.5 Client Profile).

Try Building the project now.

Answer (score 0):

remove the Qurtz reference and add new reference manually . Use  reference from netXX-client folder in package folder.